# RDF Publishing questions

Tags: rdf

I have the following question:
So I have selected and enhanced ssn ontology with Protege.
I import the ontology in a new file and create instances and save the instances in an rdf file.
I put the file on the server and publish it e.g on http://example.com/sensors/mysensors/
What is the next step/approach/ so :
When I click the URL of a resource that refers to this document e.g. http://example.com/sensors/mysensors/sensor1
to manage to only see the rdf description of this sensor?

Comment: It may just be too early in the morning, but I can't seem to understand what is it exactly you want to do with this rdf file?

Comment: Hi Kunal, I want to know how I can make the URIs of my rdf fileURLs, so every URI in rdf:about can be clicakable and show only that part of the instance. Do I need to make a configuration on apache, or create a servlet or any other way? Thanks

Comment: Ok I see, do you have an example for what information should be displayed once the link is clicked? i.e can you provide a snippet from your current rdf file and tell us what information should be shown?

Comment: Yes, so the rdf is full of individuals of this kind<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://localhost:8081/sensor/Tbox/XXXXX_ambient_Light:12345"><rdf:type rdf:resource="http://localhost:8079/sensor/windsensor#XXXXX_ambient_Light"/>
        <ssn:hasMeasurementCapability rdf:resource="http://localhost:8079/sensor/Tbox/XXXXX_ambientLight_MeasurementCapability:12345"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>   
  When I click http://localhost:8081/sensor/Tbox/XXXXX_ambient_Light:12345 I want to see the specific individual and not the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

So no code here, but I do have a general approach for how to solve your problem (which is what I think you are looking for, if not let me know). You do have to create a servlet, however you want to be using some sort of rdf framework underneath it to handle your rdf file. Basically what you want to have happen is when someone clicks the URL(URI) it acts as a parameter to a query method you wrote in the servlet which uses the frameworks methods to query your file.

You may want to use either the OWL API [here](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) or Apache Jena's ontology api [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) and use the URI to return a specific individual the details of which you can get from that individuals specific object and data properties. More info on owl ontologies can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/) and [here for OWL 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-quick-reference/)

Edit: I misread the example in the comments. You are in fact better off using the ontology api since you are using the `owl:NamedIndividual` tags.

Comment: Thanks Kunal, yes the general approach is what  I really wanted.